# c# function inside lock(obj)

Tags: c#

For the example below, will the lock be release before i++ is executed? In otherwords will the lock be released when a function is called inside a lock?

```
lock (lockerobject /*which is static*/)
{
   call2anotherFunction();
   i++;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lock will not be released until the `lock` block is exited. `lock` doesn't know or care what code you execute inside the block.

In fact, as a general rule, what happens inside a block is not known to what's outside of it:

```
if (condition)
{
    // The if doesn't know what happens in here
}
```

or

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(url))
{
    // using doesn't care what happens in here
    throw new Exception("Unless...");
} // Dispose will be called on reader here
```

But the Dispose will only be called because the block is *exited*, not just because a `throw` happens inside it.

Answer (score 6):

No, the lock will be released only when the code execution leaves the scope of the `lock` block.

Answer (score 3):

The lock will be held until your point of execution leaves the closing curly brace.  So hte lock will still be held when the i++ executes.

If cal2anotherfunction throws an exception, the i++ will never be executed, and the lock will be released when the stack unwinds out of the function that created the lock (there is effectively try-finally around the lock)

Answer (score 2):

No it won't be released. If you want it released, start the lock after the function call.

```
call2anotherFunction();
lock (lockerobject which is static)
{
   i++;
}
```